# creating a candle chart of a stock using flutter

Tags: python, pandas, flutter, dart, finance

I am trying to create a web application using flutter to present a candle chart of a stock given it's data in a pandas dataframe, as received from the yahoo-finance package.

Is there an easy way to present this kind of chart without creating the chart widget from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/trading_chart) package, in combination with Flask as the backend web framework.

### Here is an example how your dart's code should look like:

#### This will create the chart:

```
child: KChartWidget(
                datas,
                isLine: isLine,
                mainState: MainState.NONE,
                secondaryState: SecondaryState.NONE,
                fixedLength: 2,
                timeFormat: TimeFormat.YEAR_MONTH_DAY,
                isChinese: false,
                bgColor: [
                  Color(0xFF121128),
                  Color(0xFF121128),
                  Color(0xFF121128)
                ],
              ),
```

`datas` should be of type `List<KLineEntity>`.

#### The following functions handle the fetching of the data from the backend:

```
void getData(String period) async {
    String result = await getIPAddress('$period');
    try {
      List parseJson = convert.json.decode(result);
      datas = parseJson
          .map((item) => KLineEntity.fromJson(item))
          .toList()
          .cast<KLineEntity>();
      DataUtil.calculate(datas);
      showLoading = false;
      setState(() {});
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      setState(() {});
      print('Error');
    }
  }

  Future<String> getIPAddress(String period) async {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/?stock_symbol=$stockSymbol";
    String result;
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      result = response.body;
    } else {
      print('Failed getting IP address');
    }
    return result;
  }
```

### This is how you get the data from your backend:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
import yfinance as yf

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def get_data_as_json():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stock_symbol = str(request.args['stock_symbol'])

        stock_data = yf.Ticker(stock_symbol)
        data = stock_data.history(period="max", interval='1d')
        data = data[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']]

        r = requests.get('https://api.huobi.br.com/market/history/kline?period=1day&size=1&symbol=btcusdt')
        latest_ts = r.json()['data'][0]['id']

        temp = [ts for ts in range(latest_ts, latest_ts - 86400 * len(data), -86400)]
        temp.reverse()
        data['id'] = temp
        data['amount'] = 0.0
        data['count'] = 0.0

        data_renamed = data.rename(columns={'Open': 'open', 'High': 'high',
                                            'Low': 'low', 'Close': 'close',
                                            'Volume': 'vol'})
        data_renamed_as_json = data_renamed.to_json(orient="records")

        return data_renamed_as_json


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```